# What to do when off-topic is not shown in the flag list in Triage?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage

I ran into [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9560428) in Triage. Only one option in flag was showing, which is custom message moderation. Should I choose that and write "off-topic" manually? I got it for the first time and thought it is because of already closing the question in that reason. So, I skipped it. What should I do actually?

[image]

Comment: Is it because the question was already deleted when you got to it?

Comment: I said it in the question, "thought it is because of already closing the question in that reason.", but want to be sure, what is happening actually. @approxiblue

Comment: Not just closed, I think it's deleted entirely. I can't see it in the review.

Comment: who knows when it was deleted! let someone answer who knows the exact policy (may be a moderator or someone who knows the actual thing). @approxiblue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Next time you encounter this, refresh the page - if the question gets deleted (or closed) while you're looking at it, the review task will be invalid, but you won't see this until you refresh; the options will just be really limited.